# PL/SQL read/load from excel to database table

Tags: excel, plsql, load

The requirement is we need to create a PL/SQL procedure/function to read and load data from an excel file (.xls) to the database tables. 
The columns/fields of table wherein the the data needs to be loaded are:
LineID - Sequence ID
ColumnNum - column number from the excel file
RowNum - row number from the excel file
Value - value of the cell in the excel file

I would like to ask if this is possible? I searched and found that most of the answers is that loading from an external file is possible if the file is in csv format. As for the table format where the data needs to be loaded, the format of the source is the same with the format of the table wherein the data will be loaded.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible? Absolutely. Excel files are just data spinning on a disk somewhere - it's not like they warp space and time or require demonic intervention to parse. Have I ever seen it done? No. However, parsing .CSV files isn't particularly difficult - even SQL*Loader can handle that. Perhaps your spreadsheet could be saved as a .CSV for import purposes. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/gateways.112/e12061/configodbc.htm
then you can access your xls just like regular database table using databse link